# Does JBoss come prepacked with lots of software tools?

Tags: jboss, talend

When trying to install Talend MDM, the documentation said something rather interesting:

"JBoss Application Server comes prepackaged with Talend MDM."

That would make my life a lot easier, but I can't tell if they are trying to say that Talend's downloadable version of JBoss comes with Talend MDM, or if the open source JBoss AS actually comes with Talend?

If so, what other neat software tools come prepackaged with JBoss, and if so, how can I view a listing?

Comment: You certainly found the JBoss tools site: http://www.jboss.org/tools Some very nice stuff that integrates nicely with Eclipse, but not Talend specific; I don't know if they will work / are needed with Talend Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misunderstanding here.  What the documentation means is that as part of the Talend MDM product, the JBoss Application Server is shipped.  So JBoss is a component (actually the core component) of Talend MDM.  Not the other way round.

Talend MDM actually depends on the precise version of JBoss that is shipped with the product (it may even be modified here or there), so it is not possible to install Talend MDM into a different JBoss instance.